# How can we compare two hashmap's in java

Tags: java, hashmap

My application storing the values from database and user values and compare them. In order to store those values I have used hashmap with key as integer and list as data and store the values. It is not necessary that the key values and data should be same but all the data values in 2 hashmaps should be same

The hashmaps are like this: 
key : value

```
1-[cd,done]
2-[mb,done]
3-[core,done]
```

other one is

```
1-[mb,done]
2-[core,done]
3-[cd,done]
```

In code the above hasmap should be equal irrespective of what order the values are stored
but as of now I am not able to code it correctly...

Comment: Adding what you've already done into the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you just want to test that the values of the maps are equals not the maps themself.

Thus you can just compare the `values()` using the `containsAll` method:

```
hashMap1.values().containsAll(hashMap2.values()) &&
    hashMap2.values().containsAll(hashMap1.values());
```

You could also use the [CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) to simplify the code:

```
CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(hashMap1.values(), hashMap2.values());
```

Comment: i hadn't thought of containsAll() in both directions to do an "equals". nice work :)

Comment: actually, containsAll() in both directions isn't accurate. A,A,B equals A,B,B

Comment: What about if the collections contain A,B and A,B,C? It will return true in one direction and not the other one.

Comment: Thanks a lot i dint know this existed :)

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Map<Integer,String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    Map<Integer,String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    map1.put(1, "ABC");
    map1.put(2, "1123");
    map2.put(1, "XYZ");

    boolean val = map1.keySet().containsAll(map2.keySet());

    for (Entry<Integer, String> str : map1.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("================="+str.getKey());

        if(map2.containsKey(str.getKey())){
            System.out.println("Map2 Contains Map 1 Key");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("================="+val);
}
```